# When did chatgpt / gpt become a thing developers widely used

Tags: workflow, chatgpt-api

Hearing that most pro devs started using it about 6 months ago when it hit the news that it was powerful for completing scripts.

So when did it become something people used in production for a lot of features. Are you late to the game if you only started very recently or is this something that has been increasing productivity of coders for a fair while.

I had a look around and tried asking chatgpt but I don't know if it understands the specifics and I wanted to get a person's opinion rather than an AI.